# Bash - creating a variable out of the printed ls

Tags: bash

Im struggling with creating a bash script similiar to ps.

I just can't get it how bash works and how to make it work. Worst thing, it's first language that I don't even know how to start with and the pressure from college is making only things worse.

My plan is:

1. Create a while loop
2. Trough all the stuff of "ls /proc"
3. Create a variable out of found folder like "folder=$(awk '{print $i}')"
4. Printf the created variable and some stuff about if from /proc/i/status
5. End while loop if something happend to be not an integer.

And I just can't get it. Im facing tons of problems and googling them hard as usually when I start to learn a new language isn't helping to solve anything. I feel helpless with this task. I don't even know if my approuch to the problem is right :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [don't need or want to parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Just loop over a wildcard directly.

```
for proc in /proc/*; do 
    pid=${proc#/proc/}
    case $pid in *[!0-9]*) break;; esac
    awk -v pid="pid" '{ printf "%i %s\n", pid, "stuff" }' $proc/status
done
```

You might want `continue` instead of `break` but the shell will alphabetize the hits when expanding the wildcard so the numeric entries will actually be grouped before other entries.

The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${variable#pattern}` produces the value of `variable` with any leading match on `pattern` trimmed off. There is also `${variable%suffix}` to trim a suffix matching a pattern, and a number of other simple string manipulation facilities.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying what exactly you want to extract from the process status, so let's say you want it's name and state

Borrowing from @tripleee answer, you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh

for proc in /proc/*
do
    pid=${proc#/proc/}
    case $pid in *[!0-9]*) continue;; esac
    name=$(grep  "Name" $proc/status | awk '{print $2$3}')
    state=$(grep "State" $proc/status | awk '{print $2 " " $3}')
    echo $proc $name $state | awk '{print $1 ", whose name is " $2 " is in state " $3 " " $4}'
done
```

Which would print something like:

```
/proc/98, whose name is kthrotld is in state I (idle)
/proc/9813, whose name is WebContent is in state S (sleeping)
/proc/99, whose name is acpi_thermal_pm is in state I (idle)
```

Or, if you want to get fancy, you could print with some color:

```
#!/bin/sh

for proc in /proc/*
do
    pid=${proc#/proc/}
    case $pid in *[!0-9]*) continue;; esac
    name=$(grep  "Name" $proc/status | awk '{print $2$3}')
    state=$(grep "State" $proc/status | awk '{print $2 " " $3}')
    echo $proc $name $state | awk '{print "\033[0;33m" $1 "\033[0;m, whose name is " "\033[0;32m" $2 "\033[0m is in state \033[0;34m" $3 " " $4 "\033[0m"}'
done
```

Which would output something like

[image]